# Python imported module is None

Tags: python

I have a module that imports fine (i print it at the top of the module that uses it)

```
from authorize import cim
print cim
```

Which produces:

```
<module 'authorize.cim' from '.../dist-packages/authorize/cim.pyc'>
```

However later in a method call, it has mysteriously turned to `None`

```
class MyClass(object):
    def download(self):
        print cim
```

which when run show that `cim` is `None`. The module isn't ever directly assigned to `None` anywhere in this module.

Any ideas how this can happen?

Comment: i don't think it's possible unless there is more code than you posted...

Comment: Clearly something is missing, post more code please.

Comment: Somewhere in between, `cim` must have been used as a global variable name.

Comment: Is it possible that another module could set cim to None somehow? I'm pretty sure that it's not happening in the subject module (I can't post it, as it is long and payment processing related), I will check again for a global variable naming problem.

Comment: @leech: not very likely, they'd have to do `sys.modules['yourmodulename']['cim'] = None`.

Comment: I'd simply throw in prints and bisect to find where it changes.  @MartijnPieters: a missed assignment is still most likely, but I think once I had a mysterious None module due to a name collision and a star import.. (I've mostly learned better now.)

Comment: @DSM: I quite agree; I merely showed how unlikely another module messing with the namespace would be. :-)

Comment: Most probably causes are namespace collisions or some global assignment. *If* you are messing around with C extensions then it may be a reference count problem(I once had a polynomial turning into a read-only buffer at "pseudo-random" times...).
Without more code we can't say anything for sure.

Comment: I have a test at the bottom of the module that is demonstrates the problem. I commented the rest of the code until the problem went away. Now i know that it's definitely an import causing the `None`. I didn't think that an import could affect it, i makes me think it's something to do with the model loading in Django (as this is a models.py file).

Comment: @leech - did you ever find out what caused this? If you did, would love to know

Comment: Not exactly. I know it had to do with model loading in Django. I didn't trace it all the way. I reordered the installed apps and miraculously enough, it fixed it. I suspect that somehow there was a circular import that wasn't reported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you comment it youself - it is likely some code is attributing None to the "cim" name on your module itself - the way for checking for this is if your large module would be made "read only" for other modules -- I think Python allows for this --

(20 min. hacking ) --

Here -- just put this snippet in a "protect_module.py" file, import it, and call 
"ProtectdedModule()" at the end of your module in which the name "cim" is vanishing - 
it should give you the culprit:

```
"""
Protects a Module against naive monkey patching  -
may be usefull for debugging large projects where global
variables change without notice.

Just call the "ProtectedModule"  class, with no parameters from the end of 
the module definition you want to protect, and subsequent assignments to it
should fail.

"""

from types import ModuleType
from inspect import currentframe, getmodule
import sys

class ProtectedModule(ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, module=None):
        if module is None:
            module = getmodule(currentframe(1))
        ModuleType.__init__(self, module.__name__, module.__doc__)
        self.__dict__.update(module.__dict__)
        sys.modules[self.__name__] = self

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        frame = currentframe(1)
        raise ValueError("Attempt to monkey patch module %s from %s, line %d" % 
            (self.__name__, frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno))        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
    ET = ProtectedModule(ET)
    print dir(ET)
    ET.bla = 10
    print ET.bla
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was related with threading quirks: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code